# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; near ')' at line 1 check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: sql, reactjs

im doing a authentication login in react js, but gives me an error, i think my sql query its current. Can't understand where is the error

```
   db.query(
       "SELECT * FROM os_accounts WHERE Username = ? AND Password ?",
       [username,password],
       (err, result) =>{

           if(err){console.log(err);
               res.send({err: err})
           }


               if (result){
                   res.send(result)
               }else{
                   res.send({message: "Wrong username/password !"});
               }
           
       }
   );
})
```

This is the erro that gives me

```
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
use near ''asd'' at line 1",
```

Comment: Should it not be Password=? (Looks like a missing =)

Comment: Agree with @MTilsted: SELECT * FROM os_accounts WHERE Username = ? AND Password  = ?

Comment: Yeah it was it, thanks a lot. Past so much time waching my query and didnt notice the ?